# Azure Kinect DK raw data

Tags: azure, kinect, depth

I'm considering using the Azure Kinect for a product that I am working on but something that I saw in one of the documents that I read gives me pause:

> "The depth camera transmits raw modulated IR images to the host PC. On
>   the PC, the GPU accelerated depth engine software converts the raw
>   signal into depth maps."

I'm unsure if this is the result of a non-technical writer trying to interpret what an engineer told them or if this should be interpreted as literal truth.

I'm assuming that the LEDs are being modulated and that the phase shift is what is being used to determine the depths.  If the sensor inside the Kinect is just a regular camera that has a fast global shutter that can be timed precisely, I suppose that you could take several images in a row and work out on a pixel by pixel basis the phase shift for the light that it is receiving.  I'm working with a resource-limited embedded computer that may not have the processing power to deal with working out the depth for every pixel in real time.   Is this what is actually happening where the host computer really is determining the depth or does the Kinect directly give you distances?